# How to get distinct List from a custom list?

Tags: c#, linq, list, equality

I am using c# framework 3.5 ..

my class here

```
  public class KonumBilgisi
{

    public string Enlem { get; set; }
    public string Boylam { get; set; }
    public string KonumAdi { get; set; }
    public DateTime Tarih { get; set; }
    public byte SucTuruId { get; set; }

}
```

I have a list

List konumlar;

well, I want to get items that equal their enlem and boylam variables each other..

As you see on the photo below

[image]

I want to compate enlem and boylam and if its the equal I want to get them to different list..

I can do that with a loop but want to use LINQ but i couldnt do that. I used groupby but it doesnt wrong..

```
   var distinctList = konumlar.GroupBy(x => x.Enlem)
                        .Select(g => g.First())
                        .ToList().GroupBy(s=>s.Boylam).Select(g => g.First())
                        .ToList();
```

**EDIT**
Actually I couldnt explain my quesion well..

maybe distinct is not right word.. I want to seperate items which are equals each other..

such as:

I will take pendik items in one list
and others will be in konumlar but pendik items will be removed from konumlar list

**EDIT 2**

Okay I want to seperate the list like that

[image]

[image]

Comment: You want to extract equal or distinct items?

Comment: extract and also disctinct from the list.. I mean, I want to seperate them each other

Comment: It would help if you'd show the desired result. You're also mentioning a second list but you haven't shown it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, OK, I edited it again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there - rather than using two separate `GroupBy` calls, use a single one, with a two-part key:

```
var distinctList = konumlar
    .GroupBy(s => new {s.Enlem, s.Boylam})
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .ToList();
```

**EDIT :** To get all items *except* the ones with duplicates, modify the query as follows:

```
var noPendiks = konumlar
    .GroupBy(s => new {s.Enlem, s.Boylam})
    .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
    .Select(g => g.Single()) // You know there's only one
    .ToList();
```

The above will give you all items except the "pendik" ones. To get only the "pendik"s, use the query below:

```
var pendiks = konumlar
    .GroupBy(s => new {s.Enlem, s.Boylam})
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(g => g)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: The usefulness of that composite key via anonymous types in `GroupBy` cannot be understated. You benefit directly from automatic implementation of equality.

Comment: I think its the same what I wrote above, but I want different things, sorry for it, I updated my question, could you look at it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Distinct() Linq function, however, that does only work identical items. In case you want a DistinctBy() you can create a LinqExtensions class with a DistinctBy() method.

Here's one which I use quite common:

```
/// <summary>
///     Provides common extension methods on LINQ members.
/// </summary>
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    #region Members

    public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        HashSet<TKey> seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
        foreach (TSource element in source)
        {
            if (seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
            {
                yield return element;
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion Members
}
```

Use it as:

```
var distinctList = konumlar.DistinctBy(x => x.property && x.property2 && ...);
```

Kind regards

Comment: thank you it looks nice but I got an exception. Error 1 Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'.. ans secondly, I updated my question.. could you look for it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is what you want:

```
List<KonumBilgisi> distinctList = konumlar
    .GroupBy(k => new { k.Enlem, k.Boylam })
    .SelectMany(x => x.GroupBy(k => k.Boylam).First())
    .ToList();
```

It select unique items according those two properties, then it select unique items according `Boylam`.